# Adding Values to a LinkedList Not Working

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to do a programming problem a day on leetcode to improve my programming and am having issues adding to a LinkedList in the problem below. I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers. I know my answer isn't the most efficient, I just wanted to start somewhere and work myself up. Everything within the method is stuff I did so far. I really appreciate any help.

///

You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

Here's a picture with an example for a possible output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iED35.jpg

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

```
/**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
* public class ListNode {
*     int val;
*     ListNode next;
*     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
* }
*/
class Solution {
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

    ListNode l3 = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode curr = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(-1);

 // Take numbers from linkedList and store in strings
    String s1 = "";
    String s2 = "";
// String values after being reveresed in the right direction.
    String sR1 = "";
    String sR2 = "";

    while(l1 != null) {

        s1 += l1.val;
        l1 = l1.next;
    }
    while(l2 != null) {

        s2 += l2.val;
        l2 = l2.next;
    }

    //check
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);

    //reverse the string;

    for(int i = s1.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {

        sR1 += s1.charAt(i);
    }
      for(int j = s2.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) {

        sR2 += s2.charAt(j);
    }

//Adding the numbers together to get the final value.
    int n3 = Integer.parseInt(sR1) + Integer.parseInt(sR2);
//Converting ints to string so i can parse them into characters that will eventually be parsed into an int to return back to the LinkedList
    String fin = Integer.toString(n3);
    System.out.println(fin);


//adding the values to my final linked list that i'd be returning here.       This is the part that isn't working.
    for(int i = 0; i < fin.length()-1; i++){

    String s = String.valueOf(fin.charAt(i)); 

       int num = Integer.parseInt(s);

        newNode = new ListNode(num);

        if(l3.val == -1) {

            l3 = newNode;
        }
        else {
            curr = l3;

            while(curr.next != null){
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            curr.val = num;
        }

    }
    return l3;
}
```

Comment: _"I know my answer isn't the most efficient, I just wanted to start somewhere and work myself up. Everything within the method is stuff I did so far. I really appreciate any help."_  -- Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You are expected to explain what isn't working and ask a _specific_ question.

Comment: Hi Jim, as mentioned above I was having issues with adding new values to a LinkedList object. I stated it wasn't efficient because I was creating a lot of temporary strings and didn't want that to become the center of the conversation. I even commented the part where I was having an error. The code should work up until there and I've tested it with print statements to debug. Once I have the adding to a LinkedList working the program should execute as intended.

Comment: Try using a StringBuilder object then

Comment: _"having issues adding to a LinkedList in the problem below"_ -- This is insufficient.  Please explain exactly what you _expect_ to happen and what is _actually_ happening, and also describe what troubleshooting you've done and what you found.  Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger?  Can you pinpoint where the behavior deviates from your expectations?  If you want help, you need to make it easy for others to help you.  Just dumping your code into a question and saying in essence "I don't know what's wrong, please debug this" is off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this? The concept here is straight forward.
The requirement is to reverse the nodes and adding them. Which means you just need to choose the right data structure to meet this requirement, which provides you last in first out? Stack. Now that you have you data in a stack just pop the items from the stack and add it up and get your expected result.
There are many ways to solve this, Using an ArrayList, using LinkedList, or plain old arrays, but try to correlate the problem with a known data structure and addressing it that way would give you meaningful output consistently. I could have just pointed you to the concept but having this code will help you think on how to address a specific problem based on the user requirement. Cheers, hope it helps.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class AddTuple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> leftTuple = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> rightTuple = new Stack<Integer>();

        populateTuple(leftTuple, rightTuple, 3);
        Stack<Integer> result = addTuples(leftTuple, rightTuple);
        System.out.print("Output: {");
        int i = 0;
        while (!result.isEmpty()) {
            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(result.pop());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }

    private static void populateTuple(Stack<Integer> leftTuple, Stack<Integer> rightTuple, int count) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input == null || !input.contains("+") || !input.contains("{")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Usage: {x,y,z} + {a,b,c}");
            }
            String[] operandSplit = input.split("\\+");
            String left = operandSplit[0].trim();
            String right = operandSplit[1].trim();
            left = left.replaceAll("\\{", "");
            left = left.replaceAll("\\}", "");
            right = right.replaceAll("\\{", "");
            right = right.replaceAll("\\}", "");

            String[] leftSplit = left.split(",");
            String[] rightSplit = right.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < leftSplit.length; i++) {
                leftTuple.push(Integer.parseInt(leftSplit[i].trim()));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rightSplit.length; i++) {
                rightTuple.push(Integer.parseInt(rightSplit[i].trim()));
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    private static Stack<Integer> addTuples(Stack<Integer> leftTuple, Stack<Integer> rightTuple) {
        Stack<Integer> result = new Stack<Integer>();
        int carryForward = 0;
        while (!leftTuple.isEmpty()) {
            int addition = leftTuple.pop() + rightTuple.pop() + carryForward;
            if (addition > 9) {
                carryForward = 1;
                addition = 10 - addition;
            }
            result.push(addition);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```